# Dredd - API Blueprint Testing Tool. "Undefined" issue

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary.io, apiary

I installed **dredd** - **API Blueprint Testing Tool** and trying to test our APIary API against the implementation.

In the blueprint I have just one resource which is correctly implemented on somehost... but test fails :(

test command:
    `dredd apiary.apib http://somehost.de:8443/imp-endpoint`

output:
    `Info: Beginning Dredd testing...
    undefined`

I tried also with more options to get more information what is undefined.. like *-l verbose* and some other options. But I did not get more information about the failure :(

Does anyone have experience with it? Thank you!!! :)

Comment: Can you add some more information. Your platform (win,linux,mac), version dredd, example apib?

Comment: platform - win, dredd - v0.2.1, a test apib: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p9zexrj3g6htzlq/apiary.apib
thx a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 4):

[Answered on Github](https://github.com/apiaryio/dredd/issues/47#issuecomment-36250310) but I'll reproduce the main points here for reference:

I wasn't able to to reproduce your "undefined" problem, but there are a few issues that, when corrected, make everything work.

1. At the moment, the base url can't have a path in it (see [#43](https://github.com/apiaryio/dredd/issues/43)). This is solved in [#45](https://github.com/apiaryio/dredd/pull/45) but hasn't yet been merged. So your command should be 'dredd apiary.apib [http://somehost.de:8443/'](http://somehost.de:8443/%27) and then '/imp-endpoint' should be a prefix on the urls.
2. The URI template is incorrect in your apib file. Instead of `/api/V0/Resources/CarSharing/Cars?{lat}&{lng}&{radius}`, it should be `/imp-endpoint/api/V0/Resources/CarSharing/Cars{?lat,lng,radius}`. See [RFC6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570) for reference.
3. The line-endings should be Unix style, not Windows (\n, not \n\r). When I first ran the apib you provided, I got the error: `the use of carriage return(s) '\r' in source data isn't currently supported, please contact makers` (this is actually enforced by the blueprint parser, see [snowcrash](https://github.com/apiaryio/snowcrash/blob/aa243c13690489d09da0de9d08527d47ed006d23/src/Parser.cc#L25))

Hope that helps! I get a 401 when running the test, so you'll need to provide HTTP Basic authentication information (this can be done in the header section of the blueprint or with the `-u` flag on dredd, as in `-u username:password`)